# keep oversized image in center of list element

Tags: css

I am trying to get an oversized image to horizontally stay centered within a list element. When scaling the window down, you'll see that right side of the image becomes hidden. This is what's meant to happen, but I want the original image to stay centered thus becoming hidden left and right side. Can anyone help please?

[**FIDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/jzvkygc7/3/)

```css
#photo-container{
list-style-type: none;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
text-align: center;
}

.photo{
width:100vw;
min-width:600px 
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li id="photo-container">
 <img class="photo" src="https://brianrashid.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/NYC-FORBES-1940x970.jpg">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `position` + `transform` tricks.

```
.photo {
  ...
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byus7qgw/)**